# Class or object type

Tags: javascript, class, object, javascript-objects

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. But as far as I know about objects and classes, I have a doubt.

Isn't object type and class the same ? 
Like both are template for an object.

```
Class Newclass {
    constructor(param1,param2) {
           this.prop1 = param1;
           this.prop2 = param2;
     }
 }


const object1 = new Newclass(objprop1, objprop2);
```

Isn't this same as

```
function Newobjecttype (param1,param2) {
     this.prop1 = param1;
     this.prop2 = param2;
 }

const object1 = new Newobjecttype(objprop1,objprop2);
```

Comment: Yes, "The class syntax does not introduce a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. Classes are in fact "special functions", and just as you can define function expressions and function declarations, the class syntax has two components: class expressions and class declarations." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Can you say it in layman's terms?

Comment: They are almost the same thing yes, basically -- but not quite, syntax sugar.